# Windows 2003 registry corrupt - endless reboot

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-registry

Windows 2003 server will show the loading screen then it stops with:

> Stop c000218 registry file failure or corrupt. The registry can not
>   load the hive \systemroot\system32\config\security

Then it start a count down about dumping the physical memory to disk and reboot itself again.

I found [Error starting Windows SBS 2003 - STOP: c0000218](https://serverfault.com/questions/70267/error-starting-windows-sbs-2003-stop-c0000218)

But the config there is different directory than mine. Is it the same step to try for recovery console?

Comment: Similar concept.  Can you pull your registry from a backup?

Answer (score 2):

Booting to the recovery console to run chkdsk is an "option". However, the likely-hood of this actually fixing a problem is almost 0, so not a good option. The correct way to fix this problem is to restore from backup or reinstall Windows.

Comment: Do you mean backup of registry? I don't believe I have. Is there a tool to backup important Windows files?

Comment: Wow, there is so much wrong implied with that question, I don't even know where to begin.